# Stopping the unauthorized users from redirecting to pages after writing urls in address bar

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

Whenever the user clicks logout button he is redirected to login page then he cannot go back by clicking back button.... but if he knows the url of any page even unauthorized page.he is able to access that page..I need to do is that he cannot access any page by typing urls..Plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your web-app with [Form authentication](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb). Other alternatives are to use Session or Cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can put one session variable at the login page, insert some value only when the user gets to any page only via login page. And check for that session value in every page load, if the value not matches redirect to login page again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the session variable in the page_load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["loggedin"] = "false";
}
```

... and check the login event. If user has pressed the login button then set the session variable "true".

```
protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["loggedin"] = "true";
    ......
   ......
}
```

When the page is redirected to another page then check the status of the session variable
in page load event.

```
    try
    {

        if (Session["loggedin"].ToString() == "false")
        {
            Response.Write("<script> alert('Session Expires! please login first'); </script>");

            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            return;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sir please write the code in `Web.config`

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
             protection="All"
             timeout="30"
             name=".ASPXAUTH"
             path="/"
             requireSSL="false"
             slidingExpiration="true"
             defaultUrl="default.aspx"
             cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
             enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
     </authentication>

     <authorization>
             <deny users="?" />
     </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This code will prevent entering url in address bar without login.